# Arabic font for documentclass{exam}

Tags: exam

My code

```
\documentclass{exam}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\bfseries\large رياضيات\\مأمون }{\includegraphics{example-image}}{\bfseries\large الإمتحان الأول }

\begin{document}
مرحبا كيف حالكم, جزاكم الله كل خير 

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        الوحدة & فصول الوحدة & عدد الحصص & الفترة الزمنية & الوسائل المقترحة\\
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

All these codes didn't work.

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
```

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}
```

```
\usepackage{sexam} % wexam & sexam package
%\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,,locale=algeria]{arabic} % on sexam.sty
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}% on sexam.sty
%\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Aljazeera}% on sexam.sty
%\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Simplified Arabic} % on sexam.sty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LuaLaTeX requires the HarfBuzz renderer to show complex scripts with combining characters, but selects the old renderer by default.  This appeared to work for me (although I don’t know Arabic and apologize if the text is wrong)

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[
  Script=Arabic,
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  AutoFakeSlant=-0.03, % Are you sure?
  Renderer=HarfBuzz ]

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\bfseries\large رياضيات\\مأمون }{}{\bfseries\large الإمتحان الأول }

\begin{document}
مرحبا كيف حالكم, جزاكم الله كل خير 
\end{document}
```

It would also be possible to use `babel`.  This MWE loads Khaled Hosny’s Libertinus fonts, including Libertinus Math, as companions for his Amiri font.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=sectioning.tabular,english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic} % You might select a variant here.

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=Harfbuzz }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
          {Amiri} % Might want to load a stylistic set or activate font features.
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Sans}
% Load a sans-serif Arabic font here if needed, for example Noto Sans Arabic.
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\babeltags{Arabic=arabic} % Enable \Arabic, \textArabic, etc.
\babeltags{english=english}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\bfseries\large رياضيات\\مأمون }{}{\bfseries\large الإمتحان الأول }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    الوحدة & فصول الوحدة & عدد الحصص & الفترة الزمنية & الوسائل المقترحة
    \end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

If you only use English for short phrases within an Arabic document, you could remove the `english` option from `babel` and add `\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}` to auto-detect the language being used and switch fonts automatically.

Comment: thanks first of all.  in the second code, I couldn't write  inside a table environment .

Comment: @MamounMohammed Does explicit tagging with `\textenglish` and `\textArabic` help?

Comment: yes, but i got the first column in the last and etc, -table inverse by mirror-

Comment: I got it by this code, to change columns order ```\newcommand{\abcdresults}[5]{ #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 \\}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
 \abcdresults{a}{b}{c}{d}{f} 
 \abcdresults{2.33}{4.55}{5.66}{7.88}{4}
 \abcdresults{3.44}{5.66}{6.77}{9.00}{4}
\end{tabular}```

Comment: @MamounMohammed This would be good as a new question.

Comment: @MamounMohammed You may need `layout=sectioning.tabular` instead of just `layout=sectioning`.

Comment: @JavierBezos ,yes brilliant, thank you Mr. javier

Comment: For Arabic text, which one is better to use: polyglossia or babel?

Comment: @Diaa excellent question, the babel manual consists of  213 page, but polyglossia  just 54 page. I think it is will be a good new question,and i will follow the Q.

Comment: @Diaa There are a few features that `babel` has and `polyglossia` doesn’t, such as auto-detecting the script, a longer list of supported languages, and compatibility with certain 8-bit legacy fonts. I more often use `babel`. However, either works.

Comment: @Davislor I got an new error: Missing number, treated as zero. when I used \question ```\begin{questions}
 \question 
\end{questions}```

Comment: @MamounMohammed This would be a problem with some part of the code you haven’t shown. Check the definition of the `questions` environment.

Comment: @Davislor , would you get a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569503/221341

Comment: @JavierBezos   , if i use `layout=sectioning.tabular` or `layout=sectioning` i will not be able to use `\begin{questions}  \question  \end{questions}`, and if remove  `layout=sectioning.tabular`  i will not be able to use `\gradetable[h][questions] `

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use fontspec and polyglossia as you did in some of your code snippets. (Since you tried those already, I am guessing you are building the document with LuaLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX.)

If you want to know in detail how you can use polyglossia to activate multiple languages and switch between them, I recommend you have a look in the polyglossia manual. Here is one example (I just used Amiri as an arabic font because I had it installed already):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\bfseries\large \textarabic{رياضيات\\مأمون}}{\includegraphics{example-image}}{\bfseries\large \textarabic{الإمتحان الأول}}

\begin{document}
\textarabic{مرحبا كيف حالكم, جزاكم الله كل خير }
\end{document}
```

Which gives this output:

[image]

If you want to mainly use arabic in your document, you should probably use `\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}`. Then you don't need to put `\textarabic{...}` around every arabic text.