# error: Missing number, treated as zero. \question

Tags: babel, exam

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
%==============================================================================
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=sectioning.tabular,english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic} % You might select a variant here.
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
[Scale=1.0, Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}
{Amiri} % Might want to load a stylistic set or activate font features.
\babelfont{sf}
[Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}]{Libertinus Sans}
% Load a sans-serif Arabic font here if needed, for example Noto Sans Arabic.
\babelfont{tt}
{Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[arabic]{tt}
{ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\babeltags{Arabic=arabic} % Enable \Arabic, \textArabic, etc.
\babeltags{english=english}
%==============================================================================
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\bfseries\large رياضيات\\مأمون }{}{\bfseries\large الإمتحان الأول }

\gradetable[h][questions] 

\begin{questions}
    \question السؤال الأول:
\end{questions} 
    
\end{document}
%==============================================================================
```

Comment: The class is buggy. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386844/2388. In your case it breaks because of the `layout=sectioning`, this changes \thepage, and as the class uses it as a number it fails.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, true. thanks a lot. but what if I want to put a table  `\combinedgradetable[h][questions]` what should i use replace layout=sectioning.tabular

Comment: use a different class.